# workgroup user can't access server

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2000

i have computer1 (windows nt - old cnc machine) in workgroup named test1. With it i can access Windows server 2000 (see shared folders). Problem is that i can't reach windows server 2008 R2. It shows error `Can't find network path`. Domain (test1.com) users can access both Windows servers.
Ping IP server2008 is working, but ping server2008 name does not (want to ping different ip address).

```
 Folder:  \\ip addr. server2\folder
 Connect:  test1\user1
```

Does someone know, how to fix this problem? Thank you.

**EDIT:** I did all suggestions from Noor and Ed Fries.
Event log on WS2008:

```
 Log Name:      Security
 Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
 Date:          23.7.2013 8:45:05
 Event ID:      4672
 Task Category: Special Logon
 Level:         Information
 Keywords:      Audit Success
 User:          N/A
 Computer:      DATASRV.company.com
 Description:
 Special privileges assigned to new logon.

 Subject:
Security ID:        SYSTEM
Account Name:       SYSTEM
Account Domain:     NT AUTHORITY
Logon ID:       0x3e7

 Privileges:        SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege
        SeTcbPrivilege
        SeSecurityPrivilege
        SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege
        SeLoadDriverPrivilege
        SeBackupPrivilege
        SeRestorePrivilege
        SeDebugPrivilege
        SeAuditPrivilege
        SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege
        SeImpersonatePrivilege
```

An error on NT computer: `The network path was not found`.

**EDIT 2:**
When i try to browse on another ws2008 it says:
On windows NT: `Access is denied`.
On WS2008 log:

```
 An account failed to log on.

 Subject:
Security ID:        NULL SID
Account Name:       -
Account Domain:     -
Logon ID:       0x0

 Logon Type:            3

 Account For Which Logon Failed:
Security ID:        NULL SID
Account Name:       boke
Account Domain:     COMPANY

 Failure Information:
Failure Reason:     An Error occured during Logon.
Status:         0xc0000225
Sub Status:     0x0

 Process Information:
Caller Process ID:  0x0
Caller Process Name:    -

 Network Information:
Workstation Name:   \\PR03
Source Network Address: 193.77.60.174
Source Port:        4453

 Detailed Authentication Information:
Logon Process:      
Authentication Package: NTLM
Transited Services: -
Package Name (NTLM only):   -
Key Length:     0

 This event is generated when a logon request fails. It is generated on the computer where access was attempted.

 The Subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or Services.exe.

 The Logon Type field indicates the kind of logon that was requested. The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).

 The Process Information fields indicate which account and process on the system requested the logon.

 The Network Information fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left blank in some cases.

 The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.
- Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.
- Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do two things:

- Install the Active Directory Client Extensions: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc750223.aspx
- Make sure that NTLM V2 is enabled: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239869
- It doesn't hurt to install the Latest SP for NT 4.0 (that's what you have, correct?): http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246009

Hope this helps

Comment: I did all things. Now i can reach also windows server 2003, but windows server 2008 still cannot. And now i can ping ip address and server 2008 name. NTLM2 level 3. Is anything that i must change on server 2008?

Comment: Disable SMB2 signing on Server 2008, as a test.   http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2010/12/01/the-basics-of-smb-signing-covering-both-smb1-and-smb2.aspx  Post the specific error when trying to connect, and look in the Security & System Event logs on W2k8.

Comment: On the NT comp `The network path was not found`. Event log in edit